# Assign IP to a Java application

Tags: java, ip, web-crawler, zpanel

I've just developed a Java application that crawls a lot of websites.

My dedicated server details: Linux, CentOS, zPanel.

I have 1 IP on my dedicated server for many domains and I've just bought an additional IP to assign it to the .jar or related domain only.

How can I do this operation?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You assign an addresses to the network interface, not the application.